# What does this "to what" clause mean?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

"Correctly rounded result is representation in the result format that is nearst in value, subject to the current rounding mode, to what the result would be given unlimited range and precision." 
What does the last clause mean?
Unlimited range and precision are given to what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Given X" or "Given that X" is a a set phrase meaning "assuming that X obtains"  For example,

> I can meet you downtown in an hour, given that there are no traffic
>   jams.

That is, I can make it downtown in an hour assuming I don't run into traffic problems.

In the case of the badly-written sentence, the meaning is that the rounded (numerical) result is the closest one possible to the actual value, which could only be shown if there were no restrictions on the number of digits displayed both to the left of the decimal point (the range) and to the right of the decimal point (the precision).

Comment: This is not a challenge in any way, but I'm a mathematician and I've never heard "range" and "precision" used that way even a single time. If pressed I'd say "integer part" and "fractional part," but honestly it's really not something I talk about a lot.

Comment: I think the source of confusion is the absence of the comma before "given". I was lost for a second, too.

Comment: @MattSamuel Likely this has very little to do with mathematics and everything to do with formatting numbers for something like a spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is not idiomatic English, as there are some articles missing. But the answer is that the parenthetical phrase *subject to the current rounding mode* is inserted in between the adjective *nearest* and one of its complements.

So the meaning is *...nearest in value to what the result would be ...*